# ui-grid : directive as cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, cell, angular-ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid with the following data structure :

```
{
 name: String,
 tags: [{label: String, image: String}] 
}
```

So the grid would have 2 columns : name and tags. A row entry can have multiple tags associated to it (hence the Array).
Each tag has two properties : a label and an image, which is the path for an image file.

I've created a directive that displays tags (directiveTags for example):

For the sake of simplicity :

```
<div>{{tag.label}}<img ng-src={{tag.image}}></div>
```

How would one use this directive in the cellTemplate property of gridOptions ?
My idea was something like :

```
columnDefs: [
            { field: 'name'},
            { field: 'tags',
              cellTemplate : "<div ng-repeat="tag in tags"><directive-tags></directive-tags></div>"
            },
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the documentation for [custom row templates](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/301_custom_row_template) we can see that the `row` object is accessible from row templates, for example: `grid.appScope.fnOne(row)`. Following the example and trying to run this, the `row` object is logged to console. `row` contains the `entity` key and this is where the row data is stored.

You are very close with your example, you just need to replace `tag in tags` with `tag in row.entity.tags` and rename your directive to not contain a dash (since I haven't worked with directives before and being on my first cup of coffee, I also got stuck at this for a while, dashes in directive names does not parse).

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/P1o1GolyZ5wrKCoXLLnn?p=preview

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.grid']);

testApp.directive('directivetags', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{tag.label}}<img ng-src={{tag.image}}></div>',
        replace: true
    }
});

testApp.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.grid = {
    rowHeight: 50,
    data: [{
      name: 'Test',
      tags: [{
        label: 'Suwako Moriya',
        image: 'http://i.imgur.com/945LPEw.png'
      }]
    }],
    columnDefs: [
          { field: 'name'},
          { field: 'tags',
            cellTemplate: '<div style="height: 50px" ng-repeat="tag in row.entity.tags"><directivetags></directivetags></div>'
          }
    ]};
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was missing :)